Straightening out rumpled striped bedsheets
I was motivated to investigate this from an seeing a Greg's Hurst answer for a different question. I was curious how to find out what the sheet would look like when flattened with proper size and all as if it was a rumpled bedsheet.
I know in the general case it is impossible to always flatten perfectly for curved surfaces because sometimes a horizontal contour might be entired hidden from view, like if a tunnel was formed under the sheet that went entirely left to right.
Here is the generalized code that I am interested in:
(* Define the custom function ᚱ as an alias for RandomReal for readability *)
ClearAll[ᚱ];
SetAttributes[ᚱ, {HoldAll}];
ᚱ[args___] := RandomReal[args];

Rasterize[
Plot3D[
Sin[ᚱ[{0, 1}]*( x +  y^2)], {x, -Pi/3, Pi/3 }, {y, -Pi/3 , Pi/3}, 
  Mesh -> {0, 200}, MeshStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3.5 ], PlotPoints -> 100, 
  Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  ViewPoint -> {ᚱ[{0, 1}], ᚱ[{0, Pi/2}], ᚱ[{0, Pi}]}, 
  ViewVertical -> {-ᚱ[{0, 1}], -ᚱ[{0, 1}], ᚱ[{0, 1}]}, 
  ImageSize -> 1024
] /. l_Line :> {ColorData["WatermelonColors"][ᚱ[{0, 1}]], l}
]

which gives a sample output of:

My thought is to do a loop along the left side record the color changes, and every time the color changes by a certain color distance to record that. But I am not certain how to find the numerical arc length of the sides or how to make sure I am tracing the edge of the silhouette on one side. Finding the arc length I guess you just take a spline between two end corners, but finding the corners is not easy. I know about MorphologicalPerimeter[], MorphologicalComponents, and ImageCorners[], but they do not work well.
Here is my attempted method for finding the corners, but it obviously works very poorly:
corners=ImageCorners[testImage]
mr1=ConcaveHullMesh[corners]
bdr = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[mr1];
pts = MeshCoordinates[bdr];
ctr = RegionCentroid[bdr];
corners = {#, EuclideanDistance[ctr, #]} & /@ pts // 
   SortBy[Last] // #[[-6 ;;]] &;
   
Rasterize[
Show[bdr, Graphics[{Red, Point@corners[[All, 1]]
   , Blue, Point@ctr
   }
  ], Frame -> True
 ]
 ]

which gave:

when I used the picture from the link to the answer in the beginning of the OP. (My program is very slow too.)

Are you not satisfied with replacing Sin[x + y^2] by 0 in Greg Hurst's code?

@A.Kato The question is if you didn't know the underlying function, how to flatten from the image. There are infinitely many functions that when striped would look like a bed sheet.

I thought so. Thank you.

@A.Kato Any suggestions on how to find corners or at least get the colors along the edge so make hedgeway into the problem? A partial answer is okay, I am stuck.

Sorry, I'm not an expert in image processing, so I can't give you very good advice --- But, I just came up with the following alternative method.

Consider a straight line (or a curve) that crosses the image all the way from top to bottom. Collect the color data of the image sequentially along the curve. Since we can assume that the colored lines are equally spaced on the bedsheet, this color data will be enough to reproduce the streighted-out bedseet. If you consider multiple lines and compare the color-sequence data, say using SequenceAlignment, you can improve the accuracy. Of course, the aspect ratio of the bedsheet is not recovered by this method.

@A.Kato Thanks. I just read about SequenceAlignment because you mentioned it. I think that should definitely help. It has nice features like a gap penalty.

While this is in Python, it is related.
